# CoreImageContext's CreateCGImage producing wrong CGRect

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode, core-image, skshapenode

Code:

```
enum GradientDirection {
    case up
    case left
    case upLeft
    case upRight
}

extension SKTexture {
    convenience init(size: CGSize, color1: CIColor, color2: CIColor, direction: GradientDirection = .up) {
        let coreImageContext = CIContext(options: nil)
        let gradientFilter = CIFilter(name: "CILinearGradient")
        gradientFilter!.setDefaults()

        var startVector:CIVector
        var endVector:CIVector

        switch direction {
        case .up:
            startVector = CIVector(x: size.width/2, y: 0)
            endVector = CIVector(x: size.width/2, y: size.height)
        case .left:
            startVector = CIVector(x: size.width, y: size.height/2)
            endVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: size.height/2)
        case .upLeft:
            startVector = CIVector(x: size.width, y: 0)
            endVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: size.height)
        case .upRight:
            startVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: 0)
            endVector = CIVector(x: size.width, y: size.height)

        }
        gradientFilter!.setValue(startVector, forKey: "inputPoint0")
        gradientFilter!.setValue(endVector, forKey: "inputPoint1")
        gradientFilter!.setValue(color1, forKey: "inputColor0")
        gradientFilter!.setValue(color2, forKey: "inputColor1")

        let imgRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        let cgimg = coreImageContext.createCGImage(gradientFilter!.outputImage!, from: imgRect)!

        print("cgimg: ",  cgimg) // *** Observer this output ***** 103.0 width and height

        self.init(cgImage: cgimg)
    }
}
```

Calling Initializer:

```
// e.g. CGSize(width: 102.69999694824219, height: 102.69999694824219)
let textureSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
let shapeTexture = SKTexture(size: textureSize, color1: bottomColor, color2: topColor, direction: .upRight)
```

Passing `width/height: 102.69999694824219`, produces `shapeTexture` with `width/height: 103`. 
Seems like `coreImageContext.createCGImage` is rounding off `102.69999694824219` to `103.0`.

This results in minor unexpected output. How can I by-pass this rounding off? Or is there is any other method to generate Gradient image for Nodes?

More Code:

```
class BubbleNode: SKShapeNode {

    private var backgroundNode: SKCropNode!
    var label: SKLabelNode!

    private var state: BubbleNodeState!

    private let BubbleAnimationDuration = 0.2
    private let BubbleIconPercentualInset = 0.4

    var model: BubbleModel! {
        didSet {
            self.label.text = model.name
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(withRadius radius: CGFloat) {
        self.init()
        self.init(circleOfRadius: radius)
        state = .normal
        self.configure()
    }

    private func configure() {
        self.name = "mybubble"

        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 4 + self.path!.boundingBox.size.width / 2.0)

        physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
        physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
        physicsBody!.mass = 0.3
        physicsBody!.friction = 0.0
        physicsBody!.linearDamping = 3

        backgroundNode = SKCropNode()
        backgroundNode.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        backgroundNode.position = CGPoint.zero
        backgroundNode.zPosition = 0
        self.addChild(backgroundNode)

        label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "")
        label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.size.width - 16
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.position = CGPoint.zero
        label.fontColor = .white
        label.fontSize = 10
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        label.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
        label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
        label.zPosition = 2
        self.addChild(label)
    }

    func addGradientNode(withRadius radius: CGFloat) {
        let gradientNode = SKShapeNode(path: self.path!)
        gradientNode.zPosition = 1
        gradientNode.fillColor = .white
        gradientNode.strokeColor = .clear

        let bottomColor = CIColor(red: 0.922, green: 0.256, blue: 0.523, alpha: 1)
        let topColor = CIColor(red: 0.961, green: 0.364, blue: 0.155, alpha: 1)

        let textureSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
        let shapeTexture = SKTexture(size: textureSize, color1: bottomColor, color2: topColor, direction: .upRight)

        gradientNode.fillTexture = shapeTexture

        self.addChild(gradientNode)

        print("path: ", self.path!)
        print("textureSize: ", textureSize)
        print("shapeTexture: ", shapeTexture)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question but why not simply `frame.size` ?

Comment: @LeoDabus - sorry didnt get you

Comment: BTW, calling two `init`s after another is not a good idea. You should really only need to call `self.init(circleOfRadius: radius)` there.

Comment: You are right but, this is some strange  way to make it up. you can try to remove that init, but an error will be thrown. Saw some SO post about the same, hence came to that implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any image/texture will always have integer sizes since there are no sub-pixels in memory. So frameworks like Core Image will always round the given size up to the next integer value.

In contrast, the `frame` of a view is given in *points*, which need to be multiplied by the view's `contentScaleFactor` to get the actual pixel size (that you should use to generate your gradient). UIKit also allows for sub-pixel frame sizes, but under the hood, it will also round up when rendering the views to the screen.

Comment: Any way to get accurate size for my Gradient'ed image?

Comment: Well, images need to have discreet (integer) pixel sizes—there are no half pixels. I think it's more the frame of the view that's a bit off. How do you get those strange numbers? Are you applying an affine transform?

Comment: I have added some more related code, which create a Shape node with given radius.

Comment: I got what you are trying to mean, if there is no work-around, should i focus on creating a node with rounded Rect, to not to bump into rounding of images?

Comment: What's `self.path!.boundingBox`? This sounds like a good alternative to use instead of `frame`. You could also use the radius you create the node with to determine the size of the gradient texture.

Comment: Thanks, `let textureSize = self.path!.boundingBox.size` solved my issue.